# INSERT with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php               
include 'connection.php';
session_start();
$noteinfo = array();
$noteinfo['note'] = $_POST['note'];
$_SESSION['noteinfo'] = $noteinfo;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['note'])) {
        echo "Dobavete Komentar";
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['noteinfo'])) {
        $check = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']);
        print_r($_SESSION['userinfo']);     
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) 
                VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['mname']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['lname']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['login']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['email']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['phone']}')";
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO addresses (address_line_1,address_line_2,address_zip,address_city,address_province,address_country) 
                VALUES ('{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr1']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr2']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['zip']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['city']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['provinciq']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['durjava']}')"; 
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO notes (note_text) 
                VALUES ('{$_SESSION['noteinfo']['note']}')";
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id,ua_address_id) 
                SELECT users.user_id,addresses.address_id 
                FROM ( VALUES () )";

        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            echo "Added";
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)) {
                echo "Added";
                if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)) {
                    echo "Added";
                    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql3)) {
                        echo "Mai stana toq put";
                        header("refresh:3 ; url=profile.php");
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
    else{
        header("refresh:1 ; url=zapiski.php");
    }
}
?>
```

My question is for $sql3: I want when the forms are completed to fill the users_addresses with the id of the user and the id from the address tables.But for now the SQL doesn't fill nothing in the table users_addresses. These are my tables:

[image: These are my tables]

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I already write what i want from the query

Comment: Aren't you missing `VALUES()` in your $sql3 on the initial `INSERT` command? I only see `(ua_user_id,ua_address_id)`, not `VALUES(ua_user_id,ua_address_id)`

Comment: And then for the select, you can do an inner join select on your 2 tables where the userId is corresponding to the specific user in question, or you can match all of the user id's to get all of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

When a user is filling in values in an application and you need to look up ids for them, then a typical way to write the query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id)
    VALUES ( (SELECT u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.username = ?),
             (SELECT a.address_id FROM address a WHERE a.address = ?)
           );
```

That is, you are passing parameters into the query, using the parameters to look up ids, and then using those ids to insert into the junction table.

Comment: Nothing different,again the users_addresses table is empty

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `VALUES()` function in your `INSERT`.

`INSERT INTO users_addresses(ua_user_id,ua_address_id)`

It should be,

`INSERT INTO users_addresses(ua_user_id,ua_address_id) VALUES(some_variable,some_variable)`

You could also do,

`INSERT INTO users_addresses SET ua_user_id=some_variable, ua_address_id=some_variable`

When it comes to selecting the data, you will need to `JOIN` your tables. I suggest a `LEFT JOIN` in this matter. It is important, that the id's that you are going to match against one another in the `JOIN` are coherent, so that you are able to link the tables together. It is then up to you whether you want a specific match or not in your condition, if you are parsing a user_id (i.e. `WHERE` clause).

Example selecting specific match:

```
SELECT
  users_addresses.ua_id,
  addresses.address_id
FROM
  users_addresses
LEFT JOIN
  users ON users_addresses.ua_user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN
  addresses ON users_addresses.ua_address_id = addresses.address_id
WHERE
  users_addresses.ua_id = $some_id
```

Example selecting all matches:

```
SELECT
  users_addresses.ua_id,
  addresses.address_id
FROM
  users_addresses
LEFT JOIN
  users ON users_addresses.ua_user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN
  addresses ON users_addresses.ua_address_id = addresses.address_id
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for, and whether you need something elaborated.

An important note, you should look into prepared statements since you are using the mysqli_* extension. It will improve your security a lot, as you are open to SQL-injections at the moment.

Comment: The last sql works with no errors but there is nothing in the users_addresses table..

Comment: I dont know why but this sql doesn't do nothing at all,just escape the if statement and "works" but in reality my table is empty

Comment: You need to make sure that you are first firing your inserts to get the data into your database. You then do the selects after. If you don't get any data into your desired table after doing the insert, then that means you have no values in your variables. Try to echo out the sql and see what the sql string looks like, and whether the php variables you are trying to insert holds the correct data. It could also be an sql error issue, which it would paste to you upon echo'ing the sql.

Comment: SELECT users_addresses.ua_id, addresses.address_id FROM users_addresses LEFT JOIN users ON users_addresses.ua_user_id = users.user_id LEFT JOIN addresses ON users_addresses.ua_address_id = addresses.address_id , this is the echo of sql