# Insert INTO with 3 tables

Tags: php, sql

```
 $sql3 = "INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id,ua_address_id) VALUES ('','')";
```

I am new in php and my hint is to link 2 tables id's in in another one called users_addresses.When a user is registered in my database i want the user_id and address_id to clone in users_addresses(ua_user_id,ua_address_id)

[My tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zAQz.jpg)

[image]

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) 
            VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['mname']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['lname']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['login']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['email']}', '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['phone']}')";
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO addresses (address_line_1,address_line_2,address_zip,address_city,address_province,address_country) 
            VALUES ('{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr1']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr2']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['zip']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['city']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['provinciq']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['durjava']}')"; 
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO notes (note_text) 
            VALUES ('{$_SESSION['noteinfo']['note']}')";
```

These are my others SQL codes for adding session's data in DB.

Comment: Looks familiar...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945805/insert-with-left-join

Comment: Yes it's the same just nobody help me by the way i want and i thought to ask again only with the SQL because otherwise is confusing for the others clearly

Comment: If you add more php code, maybe can we help you with a better example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT with LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945805/insert-with-left-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the unique ID of the insert table, this example uses Procedural style:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
......
$InsertSQL =    "INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) 
                VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['mname']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['lname']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['login']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['email']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['userinfo']['phone']}')";
$ResultSQL = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // <-- execute your query
$UserID = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // <-- get the UserID

$InsertSQL =    "INSERT INTO addresses (address_line_1,address_line_2,address_zip,address_city,address_province,address_country) 
                VALUES ('{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr1']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr2']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['zip']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['city']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['provinciq']}',
                        '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['durjava']}')"; 
$ResultSQL = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // <-- execute your query
$AddressID = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // <-- get the AddressID

$InsertSQL =    "INSERT INTO user_addresses (ua_user_id,ua_address_id) 
                VALUES ($UserID,$AddressID)"; // <-- INSERT INTO user_address
$ResultSQL = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // <-- execute your query
?>
```

You should also look into SQL Injection vulnerability, check out [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just need get user_id from first sql. If you are using mysqli function, do this

```
// run your first sql: insert user
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); // or mysqli::$insert_id
```

Next, you have $user_id variable with user id.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO addresses (address_line_1,address_line_2,address_zip,address_city,address_province,address_country) 
        VALUES ($'{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr1']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['adr2']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['zip']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['city']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['provinciq']}', '{$_SESSION['addressinfo']['durjava']}')"; 
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$address_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); // or mysqli::$insert_id 

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO users_addresses (ua_user_id, ua_address_id) VALUES ($user_id, $address_id)";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: You need the database connection..`$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`

Comment: I don't think the `$sql2` statement is correct either. The OP wanted the `$user_id` and `$address_id` in the `users_addresses` table, not the `notes`.

Comment: Because this answer is incorrect if you simple copy and paste. @pablorsk has altered your `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Yeah i want them in users_addresses

Comment: Ok I fix the example. Then you insert user and address, and next you need insert both id on users_addresses, right?

Comment: First add user,then address and finally i want both id's in the users_addresses table after each time of adding data.

Comment: example updated. 1- insert user and get id. 2- insert address and get id. 3- insert users_addresses with user_id and address_id.